# Синтаксический разбор предложения "У меня была лодка, сетки и разные удочки"

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Огромная просьба! Помогите разобраться - не могу никак понять: где главные члены в предложении "У меня была лодка, сетки и разные удочки". Мне кажется, это безличное предложение, "лодка"(НЕ подлеж.) , а дополнение, как и "сетки, удочки"? или я неправа???? т.е. сказуемое "была"- но относится не к "лодка", а подразумевается "я имела" лодку и т.д... Если бы было предложение "Лодка была старой", тогда- да, подлеж.-лодка" .
или я уже торможу...:(
заранее спасибо! очень надеюсь и жду!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

> *"У меня была лодка, сетки и разные удочки".*
>
> Мне кажется, это безличное предложение.

Нет, не безличное.  Двусоставное, осложнённое однородными подлежащими ***лодка, сетки, удочки.*** Сказуемое ***была*** согласовано в числе с ближайшим к нему подлежащим ***лодка.***

Из [**Розенталя:**](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_08)

> **§190.** Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими
>
> **1.**      При прямом порядке слов (сказуемое следует за однородными подлежащими) обычно употребляется форма множественного числа
>   сказуемого, **при обратном порядке (сказуемое предшествует подлежащим)
>   – форма единственного числа. Например:**
>
> ***Несся*** тяжелый **топот** кованых сапог и крикливые бабьи **взвизги**...

Comment: спасибо огромное! думала, с ума сойду!!! Вы в точку попали- если бы было БЫЛИ сетки, удочки, лодка, я б не сомневалась, а именно из-за несогласованности каша.

Answer (score 1):

KiraMaxa, не переживайте так, это вообще весьма своеобразная конструкция, ошибки и непонимание - дело обычное. Даже академики другой раз находят, о чем тут поспорить в рамках т. н. "общей (не привязанной только к русскому) грамматики".

Тут дело даже не в "рассогласовании" (как вы его назвали), а в том что синтаксические главные члены не соответствуют семантическим.

Синонимичная конструкция: "Я обладал лодкой, сеткой и разными удочками". Вот тут семантическое подлежащее соответствует синтаксическому. Но по смыслу-то то же самое. Вот и возникает желание применить к "У меня есть (была)" те же подходы, а не получается.

А по сути - все вам уже ответили.

Comment: behemothus, КАК же вы правы! вот и я о том же..и смысловое несоответствие и рассогласование подлежащих.. вся "прелесть" в том, что это предложение не просто из упражнения.. А из экзаменационного задания за 5 класс!(!) .. Понимаете , вот как дети в этом должны разобраться, если и "академикам есть о чем поспорить"(полностью согласна).. и какими мозгами им задают такие задания  на экзамене!!!! знаете, я уже неделю мучаюсь- хочу понять сама- вконец чокнулась.. Еще раз огромное спасибо

Comment: Ну, как раз детям-то разобраться легко: они не академики и еще не отягощены "синтаксическими и семантическими главными членами", а также "общей грамматикой". Так что не переживайте, это вполне нормальное задание для пятого класса. Да и для десятого тоже. Не надо мудрствовать, здесь же всё просто.

Comment: хорошо быть умным(это про вас)! спасибо, спасибо и спасибо

Comment: @KiraMaxa, когда адресуете текст какому-то одному кому-то "умному", рисуйте "@" перед ником. А так я в сомнении, не моего ли оппонента вы так похвалили.

Comment: @behemothus,  учла :))